# Loading Multiple Files in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have 35 Csv files I want to load the data using Pig. I have tried it with the following attempts

```
1) A = LOAD '/home/mrinmoy/Desktop/Sampath Project/Household/{HLPCA-00000,HLPCA-01000,HLPCA-02000,HLPCA-03000,HLPCA-04000,HLPCA-05000,HLPCA-06000,HLPCA-07000,HLPCA-08000,HLPCA-09000,HLPCA-10000,HLPCA-11000,HLPCA-12000,HLPCA-13000,HLPCA-14000,HLPCA-15000,HLPCA-16000,HLPCA-17000,HLPCA-18000,HLPCA-19000,HLPCA-20000,HLPCA-21000,HLPCA-22000,HLPCA-23000,HLPCA-24000,HLPCA-25000,HLPCA-26000,HLPCA-27000,HLPCA-28000,HLPCA-29000,HLPCA-30000,HLPCA-31000,,HLPCA-32000,,HLPCA-33000,,HLPCA-34000,,HLPCA-35000}.csv' UsingPigStorage(',');
```

For this attempt I have got the error

```
014-10-06 00:32:07,130 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Can not create a Path from an empty string
Details at logfile: /home/mrinmoy/Desktop/Sampath Project/Household/pig_1412580582549.log
```

In the next attempt I have changed script with using SomeLoader();

```
2) A = LOAD '/home/mrinmoy/Desktop/Sampath Project/Household/{HLPCA-00000,HLPCA-01000,HLPCA-02000,HLPCA-03000,HLPCA-04000,HLPCA-05000,HLPCA-06000,HLPCA-07000,HLPCA-08000,HLPCA-09000,HLPCA-10000,HLPCA-11000,HLPCA-12000,HLPCA-13000,HLPCA-14000,HLPCA-15000,HLPCA-16000,HLPCA-17000,HLPCA-18000,HLPCA-19000,HLPCA-20000,HLPCA-21000,HLPCA-22000,HLPCA-23000,HLPCA-24000,HLPCA-25000,HLPCA-26000,HLPCA-27000,HLPCA-28000,HLPCA-29000,HLPCA-30000,HLPCA-31000,,HLPCA-32000,,HLPCA-33000,,HLPCA-34000,,HLPCA-35000}.csv' using SomeLoader();
```

But I got the error saying this

```
2014-10-06 00:39:42,905 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve SomeLoader using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /home/mrinmoy/Desktop/Sampath Project/Household/pig_1412580912789.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pig will always load all files in a directory. So you just need to specify the directory with your CSV files.

`A = LOAD '/home/mrinmoy/Desktop/Sampath Project/Household/' using PigStorage(',');`

Please also note `usingPigStorage()` is missing a whitespace. It should be `using PigStorage()`.
And you have some double commas: `...HLPCA-31000,,HLPCA-32000,,HLPCA-33000,,HLPCA-34000,,HLPCA-35000}...`

Answer (score 0):

Pig supports providing file names as regular expressions. So you can provide something like:

```
A = LOAD '/home/mrinmoy/Desktop/Sampath Project/Household/HLPCA*' Using PigStorage(',');
```

and it will load all files with names starting from 'HLPCA' in Household directory.